# UI Not Updating even after $scope variable has updated data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am getting the data for my view through a a service and assigning to the local variable using angular.copy();

```
var init = function () {
        $scope.product = angular.copy(EditItemFactory.getSelectedItem());

    }
```

[View of my UI after calling init function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILMyU.png)

```
$scope.UpdateItem = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var Data = DataFactory.UpdateItem(data);

        if (parseInt(Data) != 0) {

            $modalInstance.dismiss('Close');
        } else {
            console.log(Data);
        }
    }
```

I am passing the Update function to Update the item and store in DB.

But after Updating in DB the data is being updated in the UI

Here is the complete code of my controller:

```
(function () {

var productEditCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, EditItemFactory, DataFactory) {




    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('Close');
    };

    $scope.UpdateItem = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var Data = DataFactory.UpdateItem(data);

        if (parseInt(Data) != 0) {

            $modalInstance.dismiss('Close');
        } else {
            console.log(Data);
        }
    }

    var init = function () {
        $scope.product = angular.copy(EditItemFactory.getSelectedItem());

    }

    init();
}
productEditCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'EditItemFactory', 'DataFactory']
angular.module("SplitWise").controller("productEditCtrl", productEditCtrl)())
```

I am not getting the way to bind the changes to UI.

**NOTE :I want to update UI only after Updated data is stored in to DB**

Data Factory Code:

```
(function(){

var DataFactory = function($http)
{
    var factory = {};




    factory.getAllItems = function()
    {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/GetAllItems")
    }

    factory.DeleteItem = function(Product)
    {

        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/DeleteItem",{"Model":Product.MODEL_NUMBER}).success(function(data){
            return data;
        }).error(function(err)
                {
            return err;
        })
    }

    factory.UpdateItem = function(Product)
    {

        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/UpdateItem",{"Model":Product.MODEL_NUMBER,"Name":Product.NAME,"MSRP":Product.MSRP,"Quantity":Product.QUANTITY}).success(function(Data){
            return Data;
        }).error(function(err){
            return err;
        })
    }
    return factory
}
DataFactory.$inject=['$http']
angular.module('SplitWise').factory("DataFactory",DataFactory)
```

}())

Comment: share your code for `DataFactory`. If it's making an HTTP call, it would be async and hence you can't just `var Data = DataFactory.UpdateItem(data)`

Comment: hi @tanmay Have updated the code for datafactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http.post` is asynchronous, so the `UpdateItem` function returns `Data` before it is received from the server thus it is `undefinded`. What you want to do is wait until it's successfully assigned and then do something with it.

```
var DataFactory = function($http) {

// ...

factory.UpdateItem = function(Product)
    {    
        return $http.post("http://localhost:8080/UpdateItem",{"Model":Product.MODEL_NUMBER,"Name":Product.NAME,"MSRP":Product.MSRP,"Quantity":Product.QUANTITY});
    }

// ...

}
```

And then use `UpdateItem` function like this:

```
$scope.UpdateItem = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    DataFactory.UpdateItem(data).then(function(resp) {

        if (parseInt(resp.data) != 0) {

            $modalInstance.dismiss('Close');
        } else {
            console.log(resp);
        }
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that `$http` returns a deferred already, no need to make a new one with `$q.defer()`.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. It makes it even simpler. Updated the answer.